# Cisco Wireless Dot11Radio not broadcasting

Tags: cisco, wifi

I am using a cisco router and struggling to make the SSID broadcast.

What have i missed out?

When I try and show activity i get

```
r1-cy#show dot11 bssid 
Interface      BSSID         Guest  SSID
Dot11Radio0/0/0   0019.30f5.c110  Yes  BD

r1-cy>show Dot11 statistics client-traffic 
Clients:
```

My config is

```
dot11 syslog
!
dot11 ssid BD
vlan 26
authentication open 
authentication key-management wpa
guest-mode
wpa-psk ascii 0 mypassword
!
ip source-route
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

```
guest-mode
```

This will broadcast the ssid. Put it in the section after `dot11 ssid BD`.

Comment: thanks for the comment. i've added but still not comming up aaa session-id common
dot11 syslog
!
dot11 ssid BD
 vlan 26
 authentication open 
 authentication key-management wpa
 guest-mode
 wpa-psk ascii 0 mypassword